# Apache Spark read parquet with specific partition number

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, parquet

I have a parquet data with 506 partitions. Its size is 6.8GB.

If I simply read `spark.read.parquet(<file>)`, I will get 150 partition.

I know that I can set `spark.sql.files.maxPartitionBytes` ([SPARK-17998](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-17998))

But even I set the value to `1G`, it still read as 150 partition.

### My questions

1. How can I read parquet with smaller partition? (like partitionNum = 5) (no `coalesce`/`repartition`)
2. Where the number 150 comes from? `50G / 128M = 400` not 150

**My Enviroment**

- Spark 3.0.1
- 128 cores

Answer (score 0):

To your questions:

1. Read the parquet and use, `df.coalesce()`.
2. Take a look to the `spark.sql.shuffle.partitions` option.

If you want further information, [source](https://luminousmen.com/post/spark-partitions).

Comment: Sorry, seems I didn't explain clearly. I don't want to do `coalesce`, it will be slow.